# Is it possible to interact and see a host in my network that is hidden? (network discovery OFF)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ip

**Hello!**

First i want to clarify that am pretty new to the networking.

In this case I have 2 pc (both win 10) in my local network, where PC 2 has **network discovery** turned OFF.

**The things i do not have clear are:**

When I interact with cmd (ex: `arp -a`) to show the local IPs some of them, including PC 2 does not showing up (I understand this is fine because the discovery off, and same for some of my android devices).

I tried to `ping` the host of PC 2 into PC 1 but it just does loose the packets: is it possible to interact anyway (e.g packet sending\receiving) between PC 1 and PC 2?

Why can I list more (not all hidden and visible) hosts with terminal> `arp-scan` on Linux, but not with `arp` on windows, does it just work better or differently (I mean more hostile)?

I appreciate the help and all the information about this you can give me  :)

Comment: when i said hostile i was talking about command ARP-SCAN comparing it to arp -a from windows

Answer (score 1):

It is just slightly unclear what you are asking, so this answer may be a bit broad and generic.

If the computer is vapable of talking to other devices using tIP(v4 or 6) then it is possible to find the machine and communicate with it in a basic way- and possibly identify a bit about the system - regardless of whether Netork Discovery is on or off. This information is more limited then network discovery.

In order for computers to communicate on a LAN they need to know each others MAC addtess - and MAC addresses shpuld be globally unique.  Further - the first 5 digits/3 octets usually represent the manufacturer of the device.  (This discovery is limited to devices in the same subnet and network segment - which means "lan" on typical home networks)

arp -a simply lists the devices the computer knows about - ie the ones it has communicated with fairly recently - unless you have recently done a network scan (ie asked the network who has each address in the subnet) it is likely incomplete. This discovery is limited to other devices on the LAN.

It is possible to discover devices on a LAN that do not respond to ping. (Also there is more then 1 type of ping)

MAC address discovery tells you of the existance of a device but not its friendly nsme or other info.  It is sometimes pissible to get more detail about it by fingerprinting it - ie identifying characteristics of its network stack depending how it responds to different probes.

Comment: Yep it is true, i asked many things at the same time, but you let them very clear for me!
Thanks  <3

The only thing i have not clear enough is...
So, if a device on the same network, have the nw discovery OFF, this hide it or else?

Comment: If the device is connected using WIFI or ethernet and in the same subnet as other devices those devices can see it even if network discovery is off.